# Google AppMaker how to define page level variables

Tags: google-app-maker

Is there any way of creating a page level variable, as in a variable that all widgets in a single page have access to?

Custom style for a page is possible, any way to do that for variables?

Comment: Have you selected your top level page widget and scrolled down in your property editor to find the 'Page Properties' section?

Comment: @MarkusMalessa :) Thank you!

Comment: @MarkusMalessa, Is there a way to define app-wide variables?